# Testing order statistics and finding if it is MP test using Neyman Pearson lemma.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics

Problem:
Suppose X1,X2,...Xn follows exponential (mean=1). Only the largest values of Xi are recorded and denoted by T. To test H0:n=5 vs H1:n=10, show that the most powerful test of size 0.05 rejects H0 for T>c, for some c. Also find c.

Here my question is that I can use NP lemma for joint pdf but can I use the same for order statistics. 
Alternatively I can just redefine the problem as a RV following the pdf of Max. Of the the RV and then I can use NP lemma to solve the problem. In this case, can we say that my redefined problem and the above stated one are the same?

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is, find $c$ such that
\begin{equation}
P_0\left(\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq n}X_i>c\right)=0.05.
\end{equation}
Now, under hypothesis $H_0$, we know that $n=5$. Thus, the probability term on the left hand side of the above equation is
\begin{align}
P\left(\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq 5}X_i>c \right)&=1-P\left(\max\limits_{1\leq i\leq 5}X_i\leq c \right)\\
& \stackrel{(a)}{=} 1-P(X_1\leq c)^5\\
& =1-(1-e^{-c})^5,
\end{align}
where in writing $(a)$ above, I have assumed that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent. Equate the above expression to find out the value of $c$.

Comment: First of all I think that what you have done in (a) can only be done if they are identically distributed which they are not. Also, the problem states that the rejection criterion must be that of a  "most powerful" test which you can't claim from your procedure. You need to follow some lemma or proper testing method which can let you claim that your rejection criteria is of an MP test. Eg: Neyman-Pearson lemma.

Comment: @SohamMukherjee you have already stated that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ follow exponential distribution with mean $1$. This means that they are identically distributed.

Comment: Oh yes. Extremely sorry for that. Still what about the next part where you have to claim it is a MP test. From your workings can you claim it is a most powerful test. If so, how?